# Why does a string of numbers work differently than actual numbers in a new Date?

Tags: javascript, string, date, numbers

Why does a string of numbers work differently than actual numbers in a new Date():

```
var myfirstDate = new Date("2013, 10, 15"); //returns Tue Oct 15 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)
var mysecondDate = new Date(2013, 9, 15); // also returns Tue Oct 15 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)

myfirstDate.value == mysecondDate.value; //returns true
```

I looked at several tutorials and the idea of having a string like myfirstDate above isn't even mentioned. Does javascript automatically parse the string?

Comment: The first example fails ('Invalid Date') in IE10.

Comment: The first approach - passing a string - is meant to be used for human-readable date strings as long as they follow one of the accepted formats; this would have also worked: `new Date('2013-10-15')`. The second approach is for when you want to pass the numerical values for year, month, and day directly (and doesn't require parsing, so it's slightly faster, but not enough to be concerned about - each approach is useful for different situations).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

You're effectively invoking two different constructors.

The first one is parsed as a human-readable date:

```
new Date(dateString)
```

The second one expects 3 or more parameters, providing a year, a **0-based** month number, and a day

```
new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond]);
```

> **year**
>
> > Integer value representing the year. For compatibility (in order to avoid the Y2K problem), you should always specify the year in full; use 1998, rather than 98.
>
> **month**
>
> > Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.
>
> **day**
>
> > Integer value representing the day of the month (1-31).

Comment: There is no limit on the numeric values that can be provided for the month and date values, `new Date(2020, 200, 200)` will create a date object for 19-Mar-2037.

Answer (score 2):

Until ES5, parsing of date strings was entirely implementation dependent, though there were one or two strings that were consistently parsed by several browsers. ES5 introduced [parsing](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2) of a [version of ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), however it's not supported by all browsers in use.

It is best to manually parse date string to ensure they are correct. There are various libraries to assist with that, but it isn't difficult (2 lines of code).

Incidentally, there is no *Date.prototype.value* method, so likely you are comparing *undefined* with itself. You should be comparing the time value, so:

```
myfirstDate.getTime() == mysecondDate.getTime();
```

or just:

```
myfirstDate == mysecondDate;
```

Oh, to answer the question: when the Date function is called as a constructor [with a single string argument](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2), it is treated as a date string and parsed (see above). So "10" represents October.

When Date is called as a constructor with [more than one argument](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1), they are treated as date values so `9` is treated as October since month arguments are zero indexed (0=January, 1=February, etc.).